# Issues while generating Perlin Noise

Tags: java, game-engine, noise, terrain, perlin-noise

I've created a function to generate a 2-dimension array of Perlin Noise data, starting with a base noise array of random values between 0 and 1.

The base white noise array looks like this:[image: Random values 0-1 in 2d array]

From there, I use the smoothNoise() function to interpolate values to create good looking image (which I don't have because it doesn't work)

The smooth noise function is called once every octave. The images of what data the smooth noise function returns is as follows (octaves lowest to highest)

[image: Octave 0]
[image: Octave 1]
[image: Octave 2]
[image: Octave 3]
[image: Octave 4]
[image: Octave 5]

After all the smoothing is done the image outputted turns black. I would upload an image but it is just black so there is no need.

My Code is:

```
    import java.util.Random;


public class Noise2D {

    int width;
    int height;
    public Noise2D(int width, int height){
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public double[][] generateWhiteNoise(int width,int height){
        Random r = new Random(0);
        double[][] whiteNoise = new double[width][height];

        for(int i = 0; i<whiteNoise.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<whiteNoise[0].length;j++){
                double rNum =   r.nextDouble()%1;
                whiteNoise[i][j] = (double)rNum;
            }
        }
        ImageWriter.writeImage(whiteNoise, "WhiteNoise");
        return whiteNoise;
    }

    public double interpolate(double x0, double x1, double alpha){
        return x0 * (1 - alpha) + alpha * x1;
    }

    public double[][] generateSmoothNoise(double[][] baseNoise, int octave){
        int width = baseNoise.length;
        int height = baseNoise[0].length;

        double[][] smoothNoise = new double[width][height];

        int period = 1<< octave; //2^i
        double frequency = 1.0/period;

        for(int x = 0; x<width; x++){
            int x0 = (x/period)*period; //7/3 = 2 *3 = 6
            int x1 = (x0+period)%width;

            double hBlend = (x-x0)*frequency;

            for(int y = 0; y<height; y++){

                int y0 = (y/period)*period;
                int y1 = (y0 + period)%height;

                double vBlend = (y - y0)*frequency;

                double top = interpolate(baseNoise[x0][y0],baseNoise[x1][y1],hBlend);
                double bottom = interpolate(baseNoise[x0][y1],baseNoise[x1][y0],hBlend);

                smoothNoise[x][y] = interpolate(top,bottom,vBlend);
            }
        }
        ImageWriter.writeImage(smoothNoise,"Smooth"+Integer.toString(octave));
        return smoothNoise;
    }

    public double[][] generatePerlinNoise(double baseNoise[][], int octaves){
        int width = baseNoise.length;
        int height = baseNoise[0].length;

        double persistence = 0.5;

        double[][][] smoothNoise = new double[octaves][][];

        for(int i = 0; i<octaves; i++){
            smoothNoise[i] = generateSmoothNoise(baseNoise,i);
        }

        double[][] perlinNoise = new double[width][height];
        double amplitude = 1;
        double totalAmplitude = 0;

        for(int octave = octaves-1; octave>=0; octave--){
            amplitude*=persistence;
            totalAmplitude+=amplitude;
            for(int x = 0; x<width;x++){
                for(int y = 0; y<height; y++){
                    perlinNoise[x][y] = smoothNoise[octave][x][y] * amplitude;
                }
            }
        }
        ImageWriter.writeImage(perlinNoise,"files");
        for(int i = 0; i<width; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<height; j++){
                perlinNoise[i][j] /= totalAmplitude;
            }
        }
        return perlinNoise;
    }

}
```

The Class is defined and methods are called by:

```
Perlin p = new Perlin(256,256);
writeImage(p.smoothNoise(p.makeNoise(256,256), 1, 16), "Perlin");
```

1 is frequency, 16 is octave count
Where the data is written in the function writeImage(2d array, "name") using the following code (I don't think there is a problem with this part but I'll post it anyway):

```
public static void writeImage(double[][] data,String name){
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(data.length,data[0].length,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        for(int y = 0; y<data.length; y++){
            for(int x = 0; x<data[y].length; x++){
                if(data[y][x]>1){
                    data[y][x] = 1;
                }
                if(data[y][x]<0){
                    data[y][x] = 0;
                }

                Color c = new Color((float)data[y][x],(float)data[y][x],(float)data[y][x]);
                img.setRGB(x,y,c.getRGB());
            }
        }

        try{
            File file = new File(name+".png");
            file.createNewFile();

            ImageIO.write(img,"png",file);
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void writeExistingImage(BufferedImage img){
        try{
            File file = new File("noise2.png");
            file.createNewFile();

            ImageIO.write(img,"png",file);
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

To conclude, I believe the problem lies within the smoothNoise method, although I could quite possibly be wrong because my knowledge of Perlin Noise is not extensive. If the problem does not lie here, I assume it lies in the generatePerlinNoise() method. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I will be so happy with any suggestion, I have been trying to solve this problem for an extremely long time.

To clarify: 
My problem is that the generatePerlinNoise method returns a set of data(2d) array that makes a black image (rather than a cool noise image)
I also think that the smooth noise images are not supposed to look like they are split up into squares

Comment: As a side note: you could use SimplexNoise, an advancement of Perlin Noise. It won't fix the bug, but it will be a lot faster. ;)

Comment: by advancement do you mean more complicated, or further developed?

Comment: he means further developed and faster, especially on graphics version. What I can see on your Perlin noise is very interesting, everything looks right except the interpolation. In itself, the curve has the right gradient, but it is switched in corners, as if the corners from which interpolation happens were being flipped, or otherwise the interpolation curve itself is not taking account signs and positions of points. You shouldn# t really recode these kinds of things unless you are very interested in learning, there are hundreds of copies already. Code something new!